# Determining Time Complexity with and without Recursion

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, recursion, time-complexity

I'm learning data structures from a book.  In the book, they have snippets of pseudocode at the end of the chapter and I'm trying to determine the time complexity.  I'm having a little bit of difficulty understand some concepts in time complexity.

I have two pieces of code that do the same thing, seeing if an element in an array occurs at least 3 times; however, one uses recursion and the other uses loops.  I have answers for both; can someone tell me whether or not they're correct?

First way (without recursion):

```java
boolean findTripleA(int[] anArray) { 
    if (anArray.length <= 2) { 
        return false; 
    } 
    for (int i=0; i < anArray.length; i++) { 
        // check if anArray[i] occurs at least three times 
        // by counting how often it occurs in anArray 
        int count = 0; 
        for (int j = 0; j < anArray.length; j++) { 
            if (anArray[i] == anArray[j]) { 
                count++; 
            } 
        } 
        if (count >= 3) { 
            return true; 
        } 
    }
    return false; 
}
```

I thought the first way had a time complexity of O(n^2) in best and worst case scenario because there is no way to avoid the inner for loop.

Second way (with recursion):

```java
public static Integer findTripleB(int[] an Array) {
    if (anArray.length <= 2) { 
        return false; 
    } 
    // use insertion sort to sort anArray 
    for (int i = 1; i < anArray.length; i++) { 
        // insert anArray[i] 
        int j = i-1; 
        int element = anArray[i]; 
        while (j >= 0 && anArray[j] > element) { 
            anArray[j+1] = anArray[j]; 
            j--; 
        } 
        anArray[j+1] = element; 
    } 
    // check whether anArray contains three consecutive 
    // elements of the same value 
    for (int i = 0; i < anArray.length-2; i++) { 
        if (anArray[i] == anArray[i+2]) { 
            return new Integer(anArray[i]); 
        } 
    } 
    return null; 
}
```

I thought the second way had a worst case time complexity of O(n^2) and a best case of O(n) if the array is sorted already and insertion sort can be skipped; however I don't know how recursion plays into effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best case for the first one is O(n) - consider what happens when the element appearing first appears 3 times (it will return after just one iteration of the outer loop).

The second one doesn't use recursion, and your running times are correct (technically insertion sort won't 'be skipped', but the running time of insertion sort on an already sorted array is O(n) - just making sure we're on the same page).

Two other ways to solve the problem:

- Sort using a better [sorting algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm) such as mergesort.
  Would take O(n log n) best and worst case.
- Insert the elements into a [hash map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) of element to count.
  Would take expected O(n) worst case, O(1) best case.

Comment: Thank you.  I realized you're right about the second one, the type casting to the Integer type had me believing that it was calling the method.  Thanks again.